# Capture the output of Docker EXEC through API

Tags: c, docker, docker-exec

I'm writing a C function to take arguments "container name" and "command" to run the command inside the appointed container and return the output. I'm using [libdocker](https://github.com/danielsuo/libdocker) to call the Restful API with curl. Currently the command can be executed successfully, but I don't know how to redirect and capture the output. Here is my code:

```
char * docker_exec(const char * name, const char * cmd) {
    json_error_t error;
    DOCKER *docker = docker_init(DOCKER_API_VERSION);
    DOCKER *docker2 = docker_init(DOCKER_API_VERSION);
    char url[100];
    long http_status = 0;
    char postdata[1024];

    // Create exec instance
    sprintf(postdata, "{\"AttachStdout\":true,\"AttachStderr\":true,\"Cmd\":[\"%s\"]}", cmd);
    sprintf(url, "http://%s/containers/%s/exec", DOCKER_API_VERSION, name);
    CURLcode response = docker_post_with_http_status(docker, url, postdata, &http_status);

    // Start exec instance with its ID
    json_t * j_id = json_loads(docker_buffer(docker), JSON_COMPACT, &error);
    sprintf(url, "http://%s/exec/%s/start", DOCKER_API_VERSION, 
    json_string_value(json_object_get(j_id, "Id")));
    response = docker_post_with_http_status(docker2, url, "{\"Detach\":false,\"Tty\":false}", &http_status);
    
    ...

    return ???; // The buffer of docker2 is empty.
}
```

I found the [official Python test code](https://github.com/docker/docker-py/blob/main/tests/integration/api_exec_test.py#L63-L74) for this function, This is basically what I want. I also tested cURL command in terminal with no problem:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:2375/containers/[container_id]/exec -d '{ "AttachStdout": true, "AttachStderr": true, "Cmd": ["ls", "-l", "/"] }'
```

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:2375/exec/[exec_id]/start -d '{"Detach": false, "Tty": false}' --output -
```

and tried to modify libdocker with no luck:

```
curl_easy_setopt(client->curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_callback);
curl_easy_setopt(client->curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, docker_buffer(client));
```

```
// callback function to test output, print nothing
static size_t write_callback(char *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp) {
    printf("%s\n", contents);
    return size * nmemb;
}
```

The buffer of Docker instance to start the exec is always empty.

Comment: I see two major security issues in this setup (opening a TCP port for the Docker daemon and calling `sprintf()`); can you address these?  Where do you read back the response from the Docker daemon?

Comment: My general advice has always been that `docker exec` is best reserved for a debugging tool.  In the same way that you can't "go inside" this C program and start running shell commands, I'd avoid trying to programmatically administer a Docker container this way.  What do you actually need to do here, and can you make that work happen using a temporary container or an entrypoint script instead?

Comment: Please include the implementation of `write_callback` in your question?

Comment: @DavidMaze The response is stored in the buffer of DOCKER struct defined in libdocker. I'm trying to develop a C program to provide basic management for docker containers.  `docker exec` works fine but it would be my last resort as all the other functions are achieved through Restful API.

Comment: @ant will update later when I get back to work